# non-static variable deck cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, static, stack, non-static

I´m getting error non-static variable deck cannot be referenced from a static context from this piece of code. I would like to understand what wrong is going there. I´m new to java.

```
public class CardDeck extends java.lang.Object 
{
    private  int size;
    private Stack<Card> deck;
    public CardDeck(int size)
    {
        this.deck = new Stack<Card>();
        this.size = size;
    }
    public static CardDeck createStandardDeck()
    {

            for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.CLUBS,i)); }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.DIAMONDS,i)); }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.HEARTS,i)); }
            for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.SPADES,i)); }
        return deck;
    }
```

Comment: first thing  no need to extend Object class .Every superclass by default extends Object class.can you post your push method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your mathod as follows :

```
public static CardDeck createStandardDeck() {
    CardDeck myDeck = new CardDeck(13*4);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { myDeck.deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.CLUBS,i)); }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { myDeck.deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.DIAMONDS,i)); }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { myDeck.deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.HEARTS,i)); }
    for (int i = 1; i <= 13; i++) { myDeck.deck.push(new Card(Card.Color.SPADES,i)); }
    return myDeck;
}
```

Comment: You actually can omit `size` field altogether. You can always get the size by `deck.size()` in constant time. I don't see a point saving the `size` as a field

Comment: It throws error   symbol:   method push(Card)
  location: variable myDeck of type CardDeck
/tmp/java_AZguK4/CardDeck.java:18: error: cannot find symbol

Comment: Yeah I missed the reference to deck. Edited the answer. Should work now